# finding duplicate records in tables between two oracle schemas

Tags: database, oracle, performance, oracle11g

I have two database sachems containing millions of records  (60 - 100 million records)  (lets assume student records)
First schema is staging schema, second is the target prod schema,

I would like to check if the same user in staging schema already exist in prod schema  before i copy it over (if it exist then apply some merge logic)

I have some PL/Sql code that runs sequentially and matches records, but the process is extremely slow, even when indexing and performance tuning.

Any matchers, or multithreading of pl/sql function that can be used? Is there any better alternative in oracle that I might be missing?

One possible solution is to copy some of the data (data participating in the duplication process) from prod schema and perform the comparison in the staging schema but the copy data overhead might be the same as comparing.

sample record:

```
Student_first_name,Student_Last_name,SSN
foo,              ,bar               ,123456
```

Comment: If "PL/SQL code that runs sequentially" implies that you have a loop where you are doing row-by-row processing (also known as slow-by-slow processing) of the data, you'd be much better served to write a single set-based `merge` statement.

Comment: It will be too long answer, so giving you hints instead. Forget about merge - its slower then even sequental insert/update. You need:partitioning, batch inserts/updates and prolly temporary tables.

Comment: On the other hand if your schema/data allows it you can do as mentioned at [asktom](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::NO::P11_QUESTION_ID:6407993912330)

Comment: Hash Indexes and/or Hash clusters are worth a try. They may do better with this kind of data updates than BTree indexes.
Partition the table, for example, based on first letter of last name into 26 partitions. This cuts down the time required to locate the row to be updated. It also helps in parallelizing your processes, 
you can run 26 update jobs simultaneously, without contention.

Answer (score 0):

First - copying the data between schemas would not benefit your performance, Oracle does not perform faster on intra-schema queries.

Second - Using a single SQL to identify your duplicate records (or missing records, whichever is the smaller part of the table, and then performing your pl/sql code on these rows alone may greatly help (by storing them in a cursor or flaging them using a dedicated column), especially if the amount of data added each day is negligible in comparison to the full prod table.